# With create a vm na with two ips Google Cloud platform using in ns1 and ns2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, cpanel

Today I spent the whole afternoon trying to configure ns1 and ns2 on a cpanel server that is installed on a Google Cloud VM, but the domain does not resolve the ip, I think I'm doing it wrong, I'm doing the following form,

Creating the VM on the platform with a subnet to gain access to an additional ip,

I point the server ip on ns1.yourdomain.com
and the second ip to ns2.mydomain.com

but not one works.

Algem could I give a light of with proceed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Google Cloud is using private ips for the linux virtual machines. And then they do a 1-to-1 NAT or something like this so in the end your server has a private ip address and all the ports of the public ip that they give you are mapped to all the ports of your private ip on the server.

So you should enable port 53 tcp/udp first of all, on the Google Cloud console so the DNS will actually work on your server. By default, as far as I remember, only port 22 for ssh is allowed, all other ports being blocked. Then for your domain, you have to points ns1 and ns2 to the public ip address or at least ns1 should point to your public ip address and be sure that the nameservers defined for your domain, on your domain registrar, are ns1 and ns2 and at least one of them is pointing to your server.

Do a telnet on TCP port 53 on your public ip address and see if any traffic is allowed. Same goes for UDP.

It's pretty hard to say what is not working since you have provided very limited information but that seems to be the case.